# Making image into a link won't work

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

So I'm having some difficulties making a list of images into working links. This is an example how they are addressed in my HTML:

```
<a href="plantvb1.html" class="plant1"><img src="img/plnt1_.png"></a>
```

and then how they are referred to in my CSS:

```
a.plant1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -20%;
    width: 50%;
    top: -20%;
}
```

now, the problem is, when i put the 'a' in front of my CSS part, my image disappears... but when I do it without an 'a', there is no link.

Comment: `plantvb1.html` isn't a web address...

Comment: @im1dermike If it's another page in the same folder/site as the referring page, it's a perfectly valid link.

Comment: Use position: relative instead of absolute

Comment: @PaulRoub: Indeed.  I guess I assumed that it wasn't a value page which is why the link isn't working. But now that I see her CSS...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.plant1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -20%;
    width: 50%;
    top: -20%;
}
```

```html
<a href="plantvb1.html" ><img src="img/plnt1_.png" class="plant1"></a>
```

Comment: This is what I tried before.. but neither will work. Thanks anyways for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

The mistake here is the positioning:

```
a.plant1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -20%;
    width: 50%;
    top: -20%;
}
```

positions your link outside of your viewport (or at least outside of the parent element which may hide overflowing children), I created a fiddle where you can see that:
http://jsfiddle.net/3ajrw1yg/

So, you need to reconsider what it is that you want to achieve position-wise and change your css accordingly.

Comment: It's not the positioning, that's knowingly done and is part of my concept

Comment: In that case, and if you're absolutely sure about this (no `overflow:hidden` on a parent-element), than the code you provided is not the problem because on itself it works perfectly. Maybe there is something else on the page that is interfering? Some other element with higher `z-index` in the same position maybe? Links with a z-index can be real bitches sometimes.

Comment: Yes I did use different images stacked on each other, with z-index 1 and 3 (and then a typographic element that has to come inbetween with z-index 2) Did i use this wrong?
And I have an overflow:hidden on my div where my images are in.. is that a problem? (otherwise there were some larger images on the bottom who hat little ugly bits)

Comment: I hate z-index and z-index hates me back, so take what I say with a grain of salt. If you stack several elements, all click events will be "collected" by the top one (in your case the one with z-index:3), even if it is transparent or has a `visibility:none` rule. So your link will not receive the click element if anything at all is stacked above it, that really could be your problem.

Comment: So if I understand it well, then the images with z-index 3 should work? but that is neither the case... :s

Comment: Just to prove what I just said: http://jsfiddle.net/3ajrw1yg/1/ Now back to your problem: So you're saying, the images that have z-index 3 are also links and they don't work either?

Comment: yes, that's what I'm saying, here is an example: a.plant2 {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 3;
 left: 10%;
 width: 50%;
 top: -20%;
}
the fact is.. as soon as I put the 'a' in front of it, the image disappears

Comment: That is weird and an indication of something else being wrong. At this point I can only give you general debugging hints (please don't be offended if you already tried those): Use the debugging tools of chrome/Safari/Firefox (Firebug) to find out where your image is going. Try to run your CSS and HTML through a validator. It doesn't have to be valid but those tools are also good at pointing you to mistakes. Sorry, that's all for now, gotta go now, will check again in a few hours.

Comment: It suddenly started working.. maybe there was a bug in Coda or such (there it still doesn't work).. Thank you very much for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving it height, when you have a position absolute, you must have your sizes defined, try this:

```
a.plant1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -20%;
    top: -20%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

and you should also close your IMG tag if you're not using HTML5...

```
<a href="plantvb1.html" class="plant1">
    <img src="img/plnt1_.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: no, stand-alone tags don't need to be closed in html5, it actually isn't even valid html5 to do so. since we don't know if this is supposed to be html5, this is a bad advice.

Comment: but since we can't seen if it's suppose to be HTML5 or not, I prefer to play it safe and always close. There's no harm done in closing it, but if he doesn't close it could have problems with older browsers. Personally I don't believe it's bad advice to just play safe.

Comment: Well, you said 'always close your tags' which as I pointed out isn't true and you even agreed to that part. Giving and advice base on an assumption without even telling that you assumed something is very bad, because someone might use that advice under the wrong circumstances. Why don't just say 'if this is XHTML, you should close your img-tag'? Chances are it isn't, but that would make things clear and your statement true.

Comment: Well I'm always thinking in backwards compatibility, since as I said there's no harm done in playing safe. It won't disrupt HTML5 and It'll help with older browsers. But I'll edit the the answer to be clearer. Thanks for the correction :)